# Simple $F[T]$ module whose annihilator ideal is generated by an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules

Let $F$ be a ﬁeld and $V$ a $F[T]$-module whose annihilator ideal $Ann(V)$ is not the zero ideal.

1. Show that if $V$ is a simple $F[T]$-module then the annihilator ideal of $V$ is generated by an irreducible polynomial.
2. Is the converse also true?

I think I have proven 1 (which I am wondering if correct), but I'm having difficulty with 2. Any help would be appreciated.

My work for 1:

For any $r(T)$, $V[r(T)] = \{v \in V \mid r(T)^r.v = 0, r \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a submodule.

For any given $v$, there exists an $f(T) \neq 0$ such that $f(T).v = 0 \Rightarrow V[f(T)] \neq 0$. (Proven in textbook).

Because $V$ is a simple module and the submodule $V[f(T)]$ is non-empty, $V[f(T)]= V \Rightarrow f(T).v = 0$ $\forall v \in V$.

If $f(T)$ is irreducible, we are done.

If $f(T)$ is reducible, it can be written as the product of finitely many irreducible polynomials $p_i(T)$.

For each $p_i(T)$, either $V[p_i(T)] = 0$ or $V[p_i(T)] = V$.

Since $f(T).v = 0$ $\forall v$, there exists at least one $p_i(T)$ and one $v_1$ such that $p_i(T).v_1 = 0$. Because $V$ is a simple module, $p_i(T).v = 0 \forall v \in V$.

Because the generator of an ideal is unique, $Ann(V)$ is generated by an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: What if $V$ is the direct sum of two simple modules with the same annihilator?

Comment: How would I go about constructing the simple modules?

Comment: The usual way to construct a simple module for a commutative ring $R$ is to factor $R$ by a maximal ideal.